# How do I make my Program wait 60 seconds in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm new in the world of programming, and I decided to start learning c++ on my own. There is a project i've been working in, but I'm not sure on how to make my program wait 60 seconds. Is it possible? If it is, How do I do it?
PD:I'm using C++ 20.
I apologize for any mistake in my writing, as I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: [`std::this_thread::sleep_for( 60s )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: First and second google result for exactly your question title both give the solution.

Comment: Unless you still want some things to happen while only part of the program takes a 60 second break. In that case things get a lot more complicated.

Comment: What is the user doing all this time?

Comment: Side note: Learning C++ on your own is often the best way to do it, but make sure you have a [good text book and library of reference materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Otherwise you're going to ask a LOT of questions and many of them won't go over all that well.

Comment: @PaulSanders: my idea: it's a clock and the text needs to update only once a minute.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Could be, but why are we speculating?